# How to install gnome shell extensions offline?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I know how to go to the https://extensions.gnome.org/ website and download gnome-shell extensions, but now I need to install some extensions available there on a computer without any internet access at all. It is in a internal corporate network and there's no way I can get outside internet access on it, so I must find another way. I can copy files in a usb disk.

At my home computer, I have found my extensions at ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ but just copying this folder to the target corporate computer didn't do the trick.

Running gnome-tweak-tool gives me a "Install Shell Extension" button but I don't know how to download an extension in a format acceptable to install using this button. I have tried to point to the folder above but it didn't work either.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You are almost there. After:

1. copying the folder in the `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/`
2. just restart Gnome Shell: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> -> <kbd>R</kbd> ->  <kbd>Enter</kbd>

and the extension should appear in the `gnome-tweaks` tool (restart that one as well).

Comment: there's also a new command line `gnome-extensions install filename.zip`

Comment: Under Wayland there's no convenient way to restart Gnome Shell. Surely there has to be a way to do this as installing actual publihed extensions does not anything like this?